# How can I change the value of cells in a given column when selecting multiple rows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to be able to select multiple rows in a datatable and then if they are selected, change the value in the cells.
The code I have is:

```
private void btnSetToReceived_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetToReceived();
}

private void SetToReceived()
{
        this.dgvPod.CurrentCell.Value = "Yes";
}

private void dgvPod_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    dgvPod.BeginEdit(true);
    SetToReceived();
}
```

Comment: [SelectedCells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells?view=netframework-4.8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I get from your question is, you want to select multiple cells and then start typing and you expect all the selected cell values change:

[image]

To do so, you can handle `EditingControlShowing` event and get the `TextBox` editing control and handle its `TextChanged` event and update text of selected cells. For example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
    dataGridView1.RowCount = 4;
    TextBox txt = null;
    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += (s1, e1) =>
    {
        if (dataGridView1.EditingControl is TextBox)
        {
            if (txt == null)
            {
                txt = (TextBox)dataGridView1.EditingControl;
                txt.TextChanged += (s2, e2) =>
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
                        cell.Value = txt.Text;
                };
            }

        }
    };
}
```

The code doesn't check if the selected cells are all in the same column, however it shows in an example how to get the text at the same time of typing and also how to set value of other selected cells.